# Phonegap 3 doesn't work with Android Studio

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

It seems rather simple to me, but I can't do it at all.

I have `npm install -g phonegap` with everything successful and installing phonegap.

I have followed instructions from here http://phonegap.com/install/ i have then created my project:

```
C:\var\www\sexdiaries.co.uk>phonegap create sexdiaries -n SexDiaries -i co.uk.sexdiaries.app
```

I have then, as told [Here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface) tried to run andriod but with the following errors

```
C:\var\www\sexdiaries.co.uk\sexdiaries>phonegap run andriod

C:\Users\Hutber\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\lib\phonegap\run.js:72
    self.phonegap.emit('log', 'detecting', platform.human, 'SDK environment...
                                                   ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'human' of undefined
    at RunCommand.execute (C:\Users\Hutber\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\lib\phonegap\run.js:72:52)
    at RunCommand.run (C:\Users\Hutber\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\lib\phonegap\run.js:55:10)
    at PhoneGap.run (C:\Users\Hutber\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\lib\phonegap\util\command.js:28:25)
    at CLI.module.exports [as run] (C:\Users\Hutber\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\lib\cli\run.js:38:14)
    at CLI.module.exports [as argv] (C:\Users\Hutber\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\lib\cli\argv.js:66:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hutber\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phonegap.js:24:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

More over, I have imported the project created into Andriod Studio, but when doing so I get: `Source files for your project not found`

I know how to create a working project using phonegap 2.9. But can't work out what 3 is offering?

So the question, how do I actually get a working local android app working using phoengap 3

Comment: Off-topic - but you might want to run the text on your web site through a spell checker ...

Comment: heh, i appreciate the concern, being dyslextic spelling is certainly not my strong point. But, I'm just waiting for my copywriter to give me something. I'm no copywriter thats for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon must digging I found how to get past this:

```
phonegap run android
```

Its as simple as that.

[Edit]

You need to add platform to work with, whilst the documentation is so very very poor:

```
C:\var\www\sexdiaries.co.uk\sexdiaries>phonegap build android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
 [warning] missing library cordova/android/3.0.0
[phonegap] downloading https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git;a=snapshot;h=3.0.0;sf=tgz...
[phonegap] compiling Android...
[phonegap] successfully compiled Android app
```

Then you are good to go, doing an import with Andriod Studio will also work now as you have a project to work with :)

Fantastic.

Answer (score 10):

The command is 'phonegap run android', It is not 'phonegap run andriod'.
Try it again. I had this problem like you.

Comment: In case anyone else has trouble seeing the difference above "android" != "andriod"

Answer (score 2):

I have used phonegap 3.0 with Android Studio and its working fine. 
Please go through [this](http://code-aspdotnet.blogspot.ca/2014/01/developing-android-application-with.html)

Comment: Please point out a specific action of the linked instruction the OP should try.

Comment: `phonegap local build android` may help as well.