# How to add Android to Phonegap Platforms version 3

Tags: android, cordova, platform

After much digging, i believe that [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423444/phonegap-3-doesnt-work-with-andriod-studio) is related to me not having any platforms added for phonegap to build from. This is missing from their documentation.

When i trying to add a platofrm phonegap

**Running code**

```
C:\var\www\sexdiaries.co.uk\sexdiaries>phonegap platform add andriod
   [error] 'platform add andriod' is not a node C:\Users\Hutber\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
 See 'node C:\Users\Hutber\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phonegap.js help'
```

**Platforms**

```
Platforms:

  keyword            | local environment | remote environment
  -------------------|-------------------|-------------------
  android            | ?                 | ?
  blackberry         | ? (BlackBerry 10) | ? (BlackBerry 6)
  ios                | ?                 | ?
  symbian            | ?                 | ?
  webos              | ?                 | ?
  wp7                | ?                 | ?
  wp8                | ?                 | ?
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For some reason, you can't add platforms in an obvious way so i found this:

You need to add platform to work with, whilst the documentation is so very very poor:

**Command**

```
   phonegap build android
```

**build**

```
C:\var\www\sexdiaries.co.uk\sexdiaries>phonegap build android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
 [warning] missing library cordova/android/3.0.0
[phonegap] downloading https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git;a=snapshot;h=3.0.0;sf=tgz...
[phonegap] compiling Android...
[phonegap] successfully compiled Android app
```

Then you are good to go, doing an import with Andriod Studio will also work now as you have a project to work with :)

Fantastic.

Comment: Needing my own SO questions over and over again :0

Comment: Thanks for discovering this. The phonegap documentation is very poor and still refers to all the Cordova commands which are not valid.

Comment: I tried this solution but I still get an error [phonegap] adding the Android platform...
   [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project.

Comment: Have you added ant to your paths? Have you got `ANDROID_HOME` in your path pointing to your SDK folder?

Comment: @jamie Hutber i have same issue as Lion789 got. ant is not added to my path. how to add it

Comment: I would google this :) its not too difficult, but you'll need a guide with images if you've never done it before.

Comment: `phonegap build android` didn't work for me but didn't output any error messages. However `phonegap local build android` did output what the error was.

Answer (score 2):

your command is like this "`phonegap platform add andriod`"

But it is `android`, not `andriod`

you need to change `andriod` to **android**.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else still having problems, I found that using the run command works as well.

Comment: Run will build and then deploy to your device or emulator :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you might have them ready and working but on windows there is an ACSII bug... instead of showing ✔ and ✖ it shows ?.

http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/8/15/Using-the-PhoneGap-CLI-on-Windows-Watch-out-for-this-bug