# How to add a platform to a project with Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I would like to add the Android support for my project using phonegap 3.

I have run the following commands:

```
phonegap -v 
     3.0.0-0.14.3
phonegap create Hello com.mycompany.hello Hello
cd Hello
phonegap platform add android
   [error] 'platform add android' is not a /usr/local/bin/phonegap command. See '/usr/local/bin/phonegap help'
```

I am quite familiar with PhoneGap from version 1.0 to 2.9 but this time I am lost.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add Android to Phonegap Platforms version 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423662/how-to-add-android-to-phonegap-platforms-version-3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As from version 3 try using: phonegap build android

Comment: For local build: phonegap local build android